# How do I stop my Spark Streaming Context only after receiving all my input data?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Using a socket connection I am receiving a JavaInputDStream, which sends one JSON message per two seconds to the Spark Cluster. I have around 60 msgs so it takes about 2 minutes to receive all the JSON data.

Here is my question: how can I stop my SparkStreamingContext() exactly when I stop receiving JSON lines as inputs?

If I use the ssc.stop() method, the context stops after executing once, so I don't even start receiving data.
If I usen `ssc.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(long time)`, it also doesn't help, because it stops the context after `time`, which will always be slightly bigger then the exact time at which I want the context to stop.

As you might have guessed, my aim is to measure the exact time that my code takes to process all my JSON messages, and I am doing this to achieve it:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new   SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("sparkstreaminggetjson");
    // JavaSparkContext sc=new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

    JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(2));

    long duration = System.currentTimeMillis();

//receive and process the JSON messages

    ssc.start();
    ssc.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(180000); 

    duration = System.currentTimeMillis()-duration;
```

With this, duration is 180000, independently of the actual time it takes to process all the JSON messages.

How can I do this?
Thank you so much.

Comment: how can your consumer side know, that all data is received? Input stream have no method to decide if data is over. Two solutions come to my mind: 1) count our messages, message count become equal to predefined value - you can stop streaming context; 2) if you have met empty RDD in input dstream - stop

Comment: 3) send a poison pill

Comment: Sounds to me like this may actually be a better job for a regular Spark job instead of a streaming one.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov except that he's using a `NetworkInputStream` as source.

Comment: @maasg He can always read manually from the stream.

Comment: a side question: you mention that the intention is to measure time to process.With the intention to measure performance?

Comment: @maasg , yes that's exactly the reason why. I ended up trying a different approach, which is to get performance data like schedulling delay and processing time from the Spark REST API. I haven''t gotten it to work yet, but I will close this question if/when I do. :)

Comment: Spark streaming performance is best characterized by the #of msgs you can process in one batch interval. Instead of sending 1msg every 2secs, upgrade your producer to send n messages, then use the streaming ui to monitor processing time vs #of messages. This needs to run continuously for some time (hours?) to get a real performance figure.